# How to pass resultset to the subreport via master report's parameter?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I'm new to *JasperReports*.

I have a result set that was passed as a parameter to the main report. From the main report I need to pass it as a *datasource* to my *subreport*.

```java
param = super.getParam(param, "MY_RESULT_SET", resultSet);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("myJasper.jasper", param, dataSource);
```

The snippet from *myJasper.jrxml*:

```xml
<parameter name="MY_RESULT_SET" class="java.sql.ResultSet"/>
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="285" y="0" width="270" height="20"/>              
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{MY_RESULT_SET}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["mySubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

On doing as above I get the below Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:356)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:275)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:473)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2021)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:265)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:540)
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a `JRResultSetDataSource` and pass that instead. This should be as simple as adding:

```
JRDataSource myResultSetDS = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet)
```

Then pass `myResultSetDS` as the parameter instead of `resultSet` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried so, on passing myResultSetDs as a datasource expression to my subreport, the data is populated only in my first row. To populate it in the other rows I need to clone my datasource. ResultSetDS cannot be cloned. Is there any other solution to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand the need to clone it. Could you upload the jrxml for your subreport?

Comment: While passing datasource to subreport, we need to clone it otherwise when we have a table with multiple row the data will be displayed only in the first row. My subreport has a field <field name="MY_DATA" class="java.lang.String"/> and the field is displayed in my detail band